# Change Image Source AND Add File Name Suffix

Tags: javascript, image, url, src

How do I specify the exact file path directory for the "-hover" image (rollover effect)? Right now, this only works for images living in a child directory.

```
$(function(){
  $('.box-img').append('<span></span>').hover(
    function(){
      $(this).find('img').stop().animate({opacity:0})
    }, function(){
      $(this).find('img').stop().animate({opacity:1})
    }
  ).each(function(){
    var src=new Array()
    src=$(this).find('img').attr('src').split('.')
    src=src[0]+'-hover.'+src[1]
    $(this).find('>span').css({background:'url('+src+')'})
  });
})
```

Comment: Hm, should work for every directory that does not contain a dot. What paths have you tried?

Comment: To avoid all this you should read about CSS Sprites: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/

Comment: Could you explicitly show the `src` of an un-hovered image and what you'd want that `src` to become when the image is hovered? Also, posting a [live demo for us to work with](http://jsfiddle.net/) helps, some.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use sprites with `the background-position` css property, but you can try this, using `RegExp`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // Change the image of hoverable images
   $(".imgHoverable").hover( function() {
       var hoverImg = HoverImgOf($(this).attr("src"));
       $(this).attr("src", hoverImg);
     }, function() {
       var normalImg = NormalImgOf($(this).attr("src"));
       $(this).attr("src", normalImg);
     }
   );
});

function HoverImgOf(filename)
{
   var re = new RegExp("(.+)\\.(gif|png|jpg)", "g");
   return filename.replace(re, "$1-hover.$2");
}
function NormalImgOf(filename)
{
   var re = new RegExp("(.+)-hover\\.(gif|png|jpg)", "g");
   return filename.replace(re, "$1.$2");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `basename` from `jquery.utils` to extract the basename from your `src`. Then you split basename by ".", add '-hover', and reconstruct the path. So you needn't worry about names such as "../../css/images/image.png".

Or you can split by "/", then retrieve the last element of the array as the basename, and *that* one you split by ".".

```
var src=new Array()
// path/to/filename.jpg
src=$(this).find('img').attr('src').split('/')

var bname = src.pop()   // bname is now filename.jpg, src is { path to }
var bco=new Array()     
bco = bname.split('.')  // bco is now { filename jpg }
ext = bco.pop()         // ext is jpg, bco is { filename }
nam = bco.pop()         // nam is filename, bco is { }

bco.push(nam + '-hover') // bco is { filename-hover }
bco.push(ext)            // bco is { filename-hover jpg }

bname = bco.join('.')   // bname is now filename-hover.jpg

src.push(bname)

srcString = src.join('/')
```

You also still have to care about how you name files with a dot in the basename (e.g. "ubuntu-12.02.jpg"), and how you reassemble the split array.

Comment: Instead of `nam = bco.pop(); bco.push(nam + '-hover')` you could just `bco.push('-hover')`.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. I could also have avoided `bname` altogether. But I wanted to show the various steps, also because I wasn't (and still am not) totally sure about the OP's problem. This way, he might find something useful even if the overall answer isn't spot-on.